# Is there a way to call gnome nautilus sushi to view files using command line?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, gnome, preview

I like the file quick viewer of nautilus (using  to preview files, supporting many kinds of file types). How can I call this previewer from terminal directly? Or is there some alternative program which can be started using command line? (Just like the qlmanage of Quick Look in Mac OS.)

Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install Gloobus Preview:

http://gloobus.net/gloobus-preview/

It has a command line option that allows you to preview over 40 popular file types:

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/01/quick-file-previewer-gloobus-preview.html
http://dthpham.me/post/21425848691/gloobus-preview-in-kde

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work well on Debian.

Comment: Are you sure you mean Debian? In your post you tagged 'Ubuntu'. If you follow the second link in my post you can see that Gloobus Preview does work with Ubuntu.